# Using objects other class created

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I have python file that has a user interface, that mainly create objects of some class.
That file will be used by my colleagues, on their own computers.
In another file, from my computer, I'm willing to reach those objects that the first file generated.
What will be the best way to "save" the objects of the class, and then reach them from
my computer?
Thanks

Comment: [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Just to be clarify, the GUI file won't be used widely, so the solution should be mainly simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickle or cPickle nicely handles saving object instances (as well as anything else); documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

Two notes from when I fumbled through the a similar problem:

1. When you load a pickled object instance, you must have the object's class definition present in the namespace of the script/environment where you load.
2. Not everything can be pickled; I ran into this when saving objects that contained scipy spline instances. In your class definition, you can override the default behavior when pickling and unpickling in order to safely save and restore such attributes.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is have the script serialize the objects, and send them to your computer over the network.

As inspectorG4dget has said, you can use the pickle module to serialize your objects, and the requests library should be good for sending the objects from the client side.

On your machine, you would need a web-server/socket-listener, listening for the sent messages. You would deserialize them, and use them in some way after that.